# how to place a regression line on top of a graph of data with different legend for each group

Tags: fitting, code-request

I have this code:

```
ClearAll[groupeddata, groupeddata1];

countries = {"Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "India", 
   "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka", "Brunei Darussalam", 
   "Cambodia", "Indonesia", "Laos", "Malaysia", "Myanmar", 
   "Philippines", "Singapore", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Vietnam", 
   "China", "Japan", "Mongolia", "North Korea", "South Korea", 
   "American Samoa", "Fiji", "French Polynesia", "Guam", 
   "Hong Kong SAR, China", "Kiribati", "Marshall Islands", 
   "Micronesia", "Nauru", "New Caledonia", "Northern Mariana Islands",
    "Palau", "Papua New Guinea", "Samoa", "Solomon Islands", "Tonga", 
   "Tuvalu", "Vanuatu", "Australia", "New Zealand"};
sAsia = {"Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "India", "Maldives", 
   "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka"};
seAsia = {"Brunei Darussalam", "Cambodia", "Indonesia", "Laos", 
   "Malaysia", "Myanmar", "Philippines", "Singapore", "Thailand", 
   "Timor-Leste", "Vietnam"};
eAsia = {"China", "Japan", "Mongolia", "North Korea", "South Korea"};
SIDS = {"American Samoa", "Fiji", "French Polynesia", "Guam", 
   "Hong Kong SAR, China", "Kiribati", "Marshall Islands", 
   "Micronesia", "Nauru", "New Caledonia", "Northern Mariana Islands",
    "Palau", "Papua New Guinea", "Samoa", "Solomon Islands", "Tonga", 
   "Tuvalu", "Vanuatu"};
Pacific = {"Australia", "New Zealand"};
groupnames = {"South Asia", "Southeast Asia", "East Asia", "SIDS", 
   "Pacific"};

COVIDir21 = {0.225, 0.500, 0.226, 2.132, 13.028, 2.088, 0.431, 0.971, 
   0.056, 0.220, 0.689, 0.027, 1.974, 0.264, 1.188, 1.090, 0.266, 
   0.614, 0.010, 0.007, 0.604, 2.139, Missing[], 0.280, Missing[], 
   0.099, Missing[], Missing[], 0.157, Missing[], 0.007, 0.001, 
   Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], 0.177, 0.002, 0.003, 
   Missing[], Missing[], 0.001, 0.119, 0.047};
gdp20 = {-5, 3.8, -0.8, -8, -32.2, -1.9, -0.4, -3.6, 
   1.2, -3.5, -2.1, -0.4, -5.6, 3.2, -9.5, -5.4, -6.1, -6.8, 2.9, 
   2.3, -4.8, -5.3, Missing[], -1, Missing[], -19, Missing[], 
   Missing[], -6.1, -0.5, -3.3, -1.6, 0.7, Missing[], 
   Missing[], -10.3, -3.9, -3.2, -4.3, -0.5, 0.5, -9.2, -2.4, -3};

groupeddata = GatherBy[
   DeleteMissing[
    Replace[
     Thread[Transpose@{COVIDir21, gdp20} -> countries], 
     "Missing[]" -> Missing[], All
     ], 1, All
    ], Last
   ];

lp5 = ListPlot[
  groupeddata,
  Frame -> True,
  PlotTheme -> "Business",
  FrameLabel -> {Style["COVID-19 infection rate (2021)", 12, Bold], 
    Style["Real GDP growth rate (2020)", 12, Bold]},
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> Large
  ]
```

which generates:

[image]

I like to place a regression line on top of this graph, like this:

[image]

generated by:

```
groupeddata1 = DeleteMissing[
   Replace[
    Transpose@{COVIDir21, gdp20}, "Missing[]" -> Missing[], All
    ], 1, All
   ];

line = Fit[groupeddata1, {1, x}, x];
Show[ListPlot[groupeddata1, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[line, {x, 0, 44}]]
```

I also like to preserve the country groupings on the graph with a different legend for each group. This will allow me to see where each group is located on the graph. Somehow, the above `Business` style graph does not show all the country names (maybe too long?). I also want to have all country names to be placed on the graph. I can shorten the names with three letters later on if that is the problem.

Comment: am not sure I ubderstand the question. If you like your first graph, which has the country groupings, why don't you place the line in that graph, either as you did in your second graph or by adding it in an `Epilog->{`your line by `Line[{{},{}}]` or `Function[]` or any definition`}`.

Comment: @Nicholas G: I do not really know where and how to place the line because my first graph uses `Thread[Transpose@{COVIDir21, gdp20} -> countries]` but the second graph uses `Transpose@{COVIDir21, gdp20}, "Missing[]" -> Missing[], All` plus countries in the first graph are not grouped using my groupings. The country observations are automatically generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can (1) use country `"UNCode"`s as labels and country names as tooltip in `ListPlot`, and (2) use `ListPlot` with a large value for `ImageSize` so that all labels are rendered.

```
canonicalnames = CanonicalName[SemanticInterpretation[#]] & /@ countries;

countryToLabeledData = AssociationThread[countries, 
  Thread[Transpose[{COVIDir21, gdp20}] -> 
   (Tooltip[EntityValue[Entity["Country", #], "UNCode"], #] & /@ canonicalnames)]];

groupedLabeledData = DeleteMissing[#, 1, All] & /@ 
   ({sAsia, seAsia, eAsia, SIDS, Pacific} /. countryToLabeledData);

plot1 = ListPlot[groupedLabeledData, Frame -> True, 
    PlotTheme -> "Business", 
    FrameLabel -> {Style["COVID-19 infection rate (2021)", 12, Bold], 
      Style["Real GDP growth rate (2020)", 12, Bold]}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 1500, 
    PlotLegends -> groupnames];

line = Fit[groupeddata1, {1, x}, x];
```

We can  `Show` `plot1` and `line` with desired `ImageSize` without loosing labels:

```
Show[plot1, Plot[line, {x, 0, 44}], ImageSize -> 900]
```

[image]

Two-letter ISO code is not available as entity property value in WL.

```
allcountries = DeleteCases[Entity[_, "Antarctica"]] @ CountryData[];

iso2Codes = AssociationThread[allcountries,
   {"AF", "AX", "AL", "DZ", "AS", "AD", "AO", "AI", 
    "AG", "AR", "AM", "AW", "AU", "AT", "AZ", "BS", "BH", "BD", "BB", 
    "BY", "BE", "BZ", "BJ", "BM", "BT", "BO", "BQ", "BA", "BW", "BV", 
    "BR", "IO", "VG", "BN", "BG", "BF", "BI", "KH", "CM", "CA", "CV", 
    "KY", "CF", "TD", "CL", "CN", "CX", "CC", "CO", "KM", "CK", "CR", 
    "HR", "CU", "CW", "CY", "CZ", "CD", "DK", "DJ", "DM", "DO", "TL", 
    "EC", "EG", "SV", "GQ", "ER", "EE", "ET", "FK", "FO", "FJ", "FI", 
    "FR", "GF", "PF", "TF", "GA", "GM", "GZ", "GE", "DE", "GH", "GI", 
    "GR", "GL", "GD", "GP", "GU", "GT", "GG", "GN", "GW", "GY", "HT", 
    "HN", "HK", "HU", "IS", "IN", "ID", "IR", "IQ", "IE", "IM", "IL", 
    "IT", "CI", "JM", "JP", "JE", "JO", "KZ", "KE", "KI", "XK", "KW", 
    "KG", "LA", "LV", "LB", "LS", "LR", "LY", "LI", "LT", "LU", "MO", 
    "MK", "MG", "MW", "MY", "MV", "ML", "MT", "MH", "MQ", "MR", "MU", 
    "YT", "MX", "FM", "MD", "MC", "MN", "ME", "MS", "MA", "MZ", "MM", 
    "NA", "NR", "NP", "NL", "NC", "NZ", "NI", "NE", "NG", "NU", "NF", 
    "MP", "KP", "NO", "OM", "PK", "PW", "PA", "PG", "PY", "PE", "PH", 
    "PN", "PL", "PT", "PR", "QA", "CG", "RE", "RO", "RU", "RW", "BL", 
    "SH", "KN", "LC", "MF", "PM", "VC", "WS", "SM", "ST", "SA", "SN", 
    "RS", "SC", "SL", "SG", "SX", "SK", "SI", "SB", "SO", "ZA", "GS", 
    "KR", "SS", "ES", "LK", "SD", "SR", "SJ", "SZ", "SE", "CH", "SY", 
    "TW", "TJ", "TZ", "TH", "TG", "TK", "TO", "TT", "TN", "TR", "TM", 
    "TC", "TV", "UG", "UA", "AE", "GB", "US", "UM", "VI", "UY", "UZ", 
    "VU", "VA", "VE", "VN", "WF", "WE", "EH", "YE", "ZM", "ZW"}];
```

We can combine two-letter ISO codes with other codes available as `Entity` property values to get a `Dataset` with codes that can be used as labels:

```
columns = {"Name", "UNNumber", "InternetCode", "LicensePlateCode", 
   "CallingCode", "CurrencyCode", "UNCode", "ISOCode2"};

codezPleaze = Dataset @ AssociationThread[CanonicalName /@ #, 
  Map[AssociationThread[columns, #] &] @
   Join[EntityValue[#, columns[[;; -2]]], List /@ iso2Codes /@ #, 2]] & @ 
     allcountries
```

[image]

Replacing `countryToLabeledData` with `countryToLabeledData2` and `groupedLabeledData` with `groupedLabeledData2`

```
countryToLabeledData2 = AssociationThread[countries, 
  Thread[Transpose[{COVIDir21, gdp20}] -> 
   (Normal @ KeyValueMap[Tooltip[#2, #] &][
    codezPleaze[canonicalnames /. {a_String, _String} :> a, "ISOCode2"]])]]; 

 groupedLabeledData2 = DeleteMissing[#, 1, All] & /@ 
     ({sAsia, seAsia, eAsia, SIDS, Pacific} /. countryToLabeledData2);
```

we get

[image]

Comment: A thing of beauty! @kglr

Comment: Thank you @NicholasG.

Comment: @kglr: Thank you for this additional information about the automatic use of UN abbreviations. It is very helpful for many purposes. The figure looks perfect.

Comment: @kglr: For some graphs, `Show` does not give me a graph and  an error pops up related to these lines: `line = Fit[groupeddata1, {1, x}, x];
Show[plot1, Plot[line, {x, -100, 100}], ImageSize -> 450]`. I spent some time but I could not figure it out. In my reading, the error is related to `Graphics` used in `Show`. Somehow, `line` and `plot1` cannot be combined for some graphs not all. Many graphs work perfectly, but few. The error is `Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[Line[{{0,1},{5,2}}],Line[{{0,0},{5,3}}]].`.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, could be because you have multiple definitions for `line` and/or `plot1`. Try `ClearAll[plot1, line]` before defining `plot1` and `line`.

Comment: @kglr: yes, there were multiple definitions of `plot1` and `line` but there were also `ClearAll[]` before their definitions. When I print `line`, it gives me the right expression but when I plot `plot1` as a separate figure, then I have the problem. Not to mix up definitions, I run the problematic figures in a separate notebook, but the problem is still there.